# Why my boost async TCP server connection accept handler stops working after some time?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have created simple TCP server which accepts connections and request and do some processing. I have referred following [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html) and it is working fine. I send data to to connected client continuously and it is being printed on client side. Though after around period of 20-25 minutes, the client stops receiving any data. Also after such incident, the server shows running but now when I connect my client again to server, the server's connection accept handler doesnt get invoked. But I am able to telnet to the server's port and client is able to connect. Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without seeing your code. See http://sscce.org/ about the details you should post.

Comment: If you are running Linux, you may want to run your server with `strace -o strace.log ./prog` and see which system call is keeping it busy.